# How to print object name in class member function c++?

Tags: c++, object

Can I print object name in calss member function c++?

For example, I create an account1 object of the Account class in main, and I want to print the balance(member variable of Account class) like this.

```
class Account{ 
  private:  
     int balance; 
  public: 
     void setBalance(){ 
      //"Enter" << object_name << "'s balance : ";
        cin >> balance; 
    } 
    void showBalance(){ 
      //object_name << "'s balance : ";
      cout << balance << endl; 
   } 
}; 
int main() 
{ 
  Account account1; 
  account1.setBalance(); 
  account1.showBalance(); 
}
```

---

Enter account1's balance : 50

account1's balance : 50

---

How Can I do?

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, read the descriptions of the tags that you applied, one of them is wrong. You can [edit] your question to fix that. Now, with the object name, you mean `account1`?

Comment: You can't - in C++, a member function of an object can't directly obtain the name of a variable from the caller  (e.g. get a string `account1` from the call `account1.showBalance()`).    In other words, there is no reflection in C++.    The closest you can come is for `Account` to have a member of type `std::string`,  create a constructor that can be passed a string, and then create `Account account1("account1")`.    However, there is no clean way to prevent `Account account1("batman")` - you're still relying on code in `main()` passing a correct string.

Comment: As for your example of the `account1` variable (object): C and C++ do not have reflection (in which you can ask for a variable's name.) Variable names are only known in the source code.

Comment: Add a member variable to your class storing this kind of info and store this info there. There's no other way. Allowing access to the name of the variable makes little sense when you consider the scenarios where the instance of your class could be created: Dynamic allocation (`Account* account = new Account();`), arrays (`Account accounts[10];`), move construction (`Account a; Account b(std::move(a)); // is the name a or b now?`), ...

Comment: Variable names aren't even kept in the compiled executable (Unless you compiled with debug information).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

```sh
class Account {
  public:
     int accountNumber;
     float accountBalance;
     
     Account() {
          accountNumber = 0;
          accountBalance = 0.0;
      }
};

int main() {
    
    Account user; //make a Account object 
    user.accountNumber = 14538;  //assign
    user.accountBalance = 100.55; //You can also use cin......for user user input
     
    cout << "Amigo has $" << user.accountBalance << ". balance  valaa...!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the up arrow if the my answer was usefull ; )